# Buck converter suggetion

Tags: buck

I want to design buck converter Vin 12V V out 9V I out 400mA.

any suitable part /
switching frequency I want to use very low like 65KHz

Comment: There will be many suitable parts but you need to do some groundwork on this and not expect product recommendations because; asking for product recommendations renders your question off-topic. Find a device you think might be suitable and post a schematic with a link to the device data sheet.

Comment: hi andy i finding but getting low frequency device

Comment: Try the simple switcher range. I seem to remember right when they emerged on the scene back in the early 90s that some used 65 kHz.

Answer (score 2):

Use classics - MC34063. It operates up to 100 kHz and seems to fit your requirements well. [Link to Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF).